# Eloquent's default $attributes don't get mutated

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mutators

It seems that default values defined in the $attributes property are not being mutated before saving to the database?

I have this setup:

```
protected $attributes = array(
    'data' => array();    
);

public function getDataAttribute($value)
{
    return unserialize($value);
}
public function setDataAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['data'] = serialize($value);
}
```

All I get is database field filled with literally 'Array' and a preg_replace error. Upon specifying the default attribute in an overridden `save()` method it does get mutated.

Can anyone confirm this and/or has suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us how you insert/update to database.

Comment: Using `Model::create()`. But the same story is true for `Model::save()` or `Model::update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a default variable on the object itself, which is outside the function of a mutator.

The best option is probably to include the default in the constructor of the model, so they are called and mutated when the object is created. I think something like this should work:

```
function __construct($attributes = array()) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->data = array();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of this workaround as well. But still, `$attributes` not being mutated seems to me like a framework deficiency, isn't it? Should I open an issue for this?

Comment: Its not a deficiency - no. A mutator is applied on a "setter". You have not run a "setter" - you have defined an object default. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Just to clarify - the attribute is "mutated" when you "set" it - not when you "save" it.